# Filling in Missing dates with missing values by a specific column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
Name        Date       Quiz    Homework   
John      11-01-02      40        10
John      11-01-03      47        20
John      11-01-04      41        10
John      11-01-08      35        10
John      11-01-10      43        15
John      11-01-13      40        10
Adam      11-01-05      41        10
Adam      11-01-08      41        15
Adam      11-01-14      49        10
Adam      11-01-19      40        20
Adam      11-01-21      40        10
```

You can see that there are some time gaps. I would like to fill in those time gaps by name and replace the quiz, homework scores for those missing dates with zero. Thus, the final outcome I want would be the following

```
Name        Date       Quiz    Homework   
John      11-01-02      40        10
John      11-01-03      47        20
John      11-01-04      41        10
John      11-01-05      0          0
John      11-01-06      0          0
John      11-01-07      0          0
John      11-01-08      35        10
John      11-01-09      0          0
John      11-01-10      43        15
John      11-01-11      0          0
John      11-01-12      0          0
John      11-01-13      40        10
Adam      11-01-05      41        10
Adam      11-01-06      0          0
Adam      11-01-07      0          0
Adam      11-01-08      41        15
Adam      11-01-09      0          0
Adam      11-01-10      0          0
Adam      11-01-11      0          0
Adam      11-01-12      0          0
Adam      11-01-13      0          0
Adam      11-01-14      49        10
Adam      11-01-15      0          0
Adam      11-01-16      0          0
Adam      11-01-17      0          0
Adam      11-01-18      0          0
Adam      11-01-19      40        20
Adam      11-01-20      0          0
Adam      11-01-21      40        10
```

Is there a fast way of doing it? What I did was the following:

```
1) Find a minimum, maximum dates by name
2) For each name, create a sequence of dates from minimum, maximum dates found in step 1)
3) Join the table created in step 2) with the original table. 
4) replace NA values in Quiz, Homework by zero
```

but that was rather slow. I was wondering if there's a fast way of doing it.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried even if it's slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate) # for easier year conversion

df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", 
                               "John", "Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Adam"), 
                      Date = c("11-01-02", "11-01-03", "11-01-04", 
                               "11-01-08", "11-01-10", "11-01-13", 
                               "11-01-05", "11-01-08", "11-01-14", 
                               "11-01-19", "11-01-21"), 
                      Quiz = c(40L, 47L, 41L, 35L, 43L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 49L, 40L, 40L), 
                      Homework = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 
                                   10L, 15L, 10L, 20L, 10L)), 
                      .Names = c("Name", "Date", "Quiz", "Homework"), 
                      class = "data.frame", 
                      row.names = c(NA, -11L))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_date(Date, "%C-%m-%d")) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "1 day"), 
           fill = list(Quiz = 0, Homework = 0))

   Name       Date Quiz Homework
1  Adam 2011-01-05   41       10
2  Adam 2011-01-06    0        0
3  Adam 2011-01-07    0        0
4  Adam 2011-01-08   41       15
5  Adam 2011-01-09    0        0
6  Adam 2011-01-10    0        0
7  Adam 2011-01-11    0        0
8  Adam 2011-01-12    0        0
9  Adam 2011-01-13    0        0
10 Adam 2011-01-14   49       10
11 Adam 2011-01-15    0        0
12 Adam 2011-01-16    0        0
13 Adam 2011-01-17    0        0
14 Adam 2011-01-18    0        0
15 Adam 2011-01-19   40       20
16 Adam 2011-01-20    0        0
17 Adam 2011-01-21   40       10
18 John 2011-01-02   40       10
19 John 2011-01-03   47       20
20 John 2011-01-04   41       10
21 John 2011-01-05    0        0
22 John 2011-01-06    0        0
23 John 2011-01-07    0        0
24 John 2011-01-08   35       10
25 John 2011-01-09    0        0
26 John 2011-01-10   43       15
27 John 2011-01-11    0        0
28 John 2011-01-12    0        0
29 John 2011-01-13   40       10
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `data.table` package which should be fast:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread("Name        Date       Quiz    Homework   
John      11-01-02      40        10
John      11-01-03      47        20
John      11-01-04      41        10
John      11-01-08      35        10
John      11-01-10      43        15
John      11-01-13      40        10
Adam      11-01-05      41        10
Adam      11-01-08      41        15
Adam      11-01-14      49        10
Adam      11-01-19      40        20
Adam      11-01-21      40        10")
DT[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%y-%m-%d")]

DT[DT[, .(Date=seq(min(Date), max(Date), by="1 day")), by=.(Name)],
    on=.(Name, Date)][,
        ':=' (
            Quiz = ifelse(is.na(Quiz), 0, Quiz),
            Homework = ifelse(is.na(Homework), 0, Homework)
        )]
```

Explanation:

1. Create the sequence of dates using `allDates <- DT[,
   .(Date=seq(min(Date), max(Date), by="1 day")), by=.(Name)]`
2. Join
   with original dataset using `DT[allDates, on=.(Name, Date)]`
3. Finally, replace NAs with 0